2-lane eDP LCD panel on 1-lane input
I am thinking of upgrading the stock LCD panel on my Asus laptop (an Asus PRO BU401LG) to an FHD one.
The stock panel (1600x900) uses a 1-lane eDP interface, while the FHD one I'm eyeing uses a 2-lane eDP interface (like most FHD panels). My questions:-

Assuming that the pinouts are industry standard (and therefore not an issue), what will happen if I try to run a 2-lane panel on a 1-lane input? Will it work fine, but be limited to <FHD resolutions, or work with image issues (for example, flickering), or just not work at all?

There are 1-lane and 2-lane eDP cables. But is it possible that even with a full 30-pin eDP connector + 2-lane cable, the laptop can only output on 1 lane? For example, due to not routing traces to the Channel 1 lanes on the motherboard PCB, or the eDP driver IC used etc.


I have Googled these questions to death with no definite answer. :(
